# Cassandra cluster upgrade 3.x -> 4.x fails with internode encryption = none

Tags: cassandra

I have a Docker swarm cluster with 3 distinct Cassandra services (named cassandra7, cassandra8, cassandra9) running on 3 different servers. The 3 services are running the version 3.11.16, using the official Cassandra image 3.11.16 on Docker Hub. The first service is configured just with the following environment variables

```
CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS="tasks.cassandra7"
CASSANDRA_SEEDS="tasks.cassandra7,tasks.cassandra9"
```

which in turn, at startup, modifies the cassandra.yaml. So for instance the cassandra.yaml for the first service contains the following (and the rest is the image default):

```
  # grep tasks /etc/cassandra/cassandra.yaml
        - seeds: "tasks.cassandra7,tasks.cassandra9"
  listen_address: tasks.cassandra7
  broadcast_address: tasks.cassandra7
  broadcast_rpc_address: tasks.cassandra7
```

Other services (8 and 9) have a similar configuration, obviously with a different `CASSANDRA_LISTEN_ADDRESS` (`tasks.cassandra8` and `tasks.cassandra9`).

The cluster is running smoothly and all the nodes are perfectly able to rejoin the cluster whichever event occurs, thanks to the Docker Swarm `tasks.cassandraXXX` "hostname": i can kill a Docker container waiting for Docker swarm to restart it, force update it in order to force a restart, scale to 0 and then 1 the service, restart an entire server, turn off and then turn on all the 3 servers. Never found an issue on this.

I also just completed a full upgrade of the cluster from version 2.2.8 to 3.11.16 (simply upgrading the Docker official image associated with the services) without issues. I was also able, thanks to a 2.2.8 snapshot on each server, to perform a full downgrade to 2.2.8 and back to 3.11.16 again. I finally issued a `nodetool upgradesstables` on all nodes, so my SSTables have now the me-* prefix.

The problem I'm facing right now is the upgrade from 3.11.16 to 4.x. The procedure that I follow is very simple:

1. I start from the cassandra7 service (which is a seed node)
2. `nodetool drain`
3. Wait for the `DRAINING ... DRAINED` messages to appear in the log
4. Upgrade the Docker image of cassandra7 to the official 4.1.3 version

The procedure is exactly the same I followed for the upgrade 2.2.8 --> 3.11.16, obviously with a different version at step 4. Unfortunately the upgrade 3.x --> 4.x is not working, the cassandra7 service restarts and attempts to communicate with the other seed node (cassandra9) but the log of cassandra7 shows the following:

```
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] 2023-12-06 17:15:04,727 OutboundConnectionInitiator.java:390 - Failed to connect to peer tasks.cassandra9/10.0.2.196:7000(tasks.cassandra9/10.0.2.196:7000)
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
```

In the log of the peer (cassandra9) there is nothing after the abovementioned step #4. So only cassandra7 is saying something in the logs. I checked system.log and debug.log on cassandra9 but there is nothing related to cassandra7 trying to handshake.

I tried with multiple versions (4.0.11 but also 4.0.0) but the outcome is always the same. Of course when I follow the steps 1..3, then restore the 3.x snapshot and finally perform the step #4 using the official 3.11.16 version the node 7 restarts correctly and joins the cluster.

I suspect this could be related to the port 7000 now (with Cassandra 4.x) supporting both encrypted and unencrypted traffic. As stated previously I'm using the untouched official Cassandra images so all my cluster, inside the Docker Swarm, is not (and has never been) configured with encryption.

I can also add the following: if I perform the 4 above steps also for the cassandra9 and cassandra8 services, in the end the cluster works. But this is not acceptable, because the cluster is unavailable until I finish the full upgrade of all nodes: I need to perform a step-update, one node after the other, where only 1 node is temporarily down and the other N-1 stay up.

Any idea on how to further investigate the issue? Thanks

In origin I posted the issue on the CASSANDRA Jira but they suggested to move the question here on StackExchange. The Jira [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-19178)  includes the relevant cassandra7 logs both for the upgrade (not working) and for the downgrade (working).

**Update**

Using `nodetool setlogginglevel org.apache.cassandra TRACE` on both the 4.x upgraded node (cassandra7) and on the running 3.x seed node (cassandra9) I was able to isolate the relevant logs:

On cassandra7:

```
TRACE [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] 2023-12-06 22:16:56,410 EndpointMessagingVersions.java:67 - Assuming current protocol version for tasks.cassandra9/10.0.2.92:7000
TRACE [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] 2023-12-06 22:16:56,410 OutboundConnectionInitiator.java:131 - creating outbound bootstrap to peer: (tasks.cassandra9/10.0.2.92:7000, tasks.cassandra9/10.0.2.92:7000), framing: CRC, encryption: unencrypted, requestVersion: 12
TRACE [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] 2023-12-06 22:16:56,411 OutboundConnectionInitiator.java:236 - starting handshake with peer tasks.cassandra9/10.0.2.92:7000(tasks.cassandra9/10.0.2.92:7000), msg = Initiate(request: 12, min: 10, max: 12, type: URGENT_MESSAGES, framing: true, from: tasks.cassandra7/10.0.2.137:7000)
INFO  [Messaging-EventLoop-3-3] 2023-12-06 22:16:56,412 OutboundConnectionInitiator.java:390 - Failed to connect to peer tasks.cassandra9/10.0.2.92:7000(tasks.cassandra9/10.0.2.92:7000)
io.netty.channel.unix.Errors$NativeIoException: readAddress(..) failed: Connection reset by peer
```

On cassandra9:

```
TRACE [ACCEPT-tasks.cassandra9/10.0.2.92] 2023-12-06 22:16:56,411 MessagingService.java:1315 - Connection version 12 from /10.0.2.137
TRACE [MessagingService-Incoming-/10.0.2.137] 2023-12-06 22:16:56,412 IncomingTcpConnection.java:111 - IOException reading from socket; closing
java.io.IOException: Peer-used messaging version 12 is larger than max supported 11
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.receiveMessages(IncomingTcpConnection.java:153)
        at org.apache.cassandra.net.IncomingTcpConnection.run(IncomingTcpConnection.java:98)
TRACE [MessagingService-Incoming-/10.0.2.137] 2023-12-06 22:16:56,412 IncomingTcpConnection.java:125 - Closing socket Socket[addr=/10.0.2.137,port=45680,localport=7000] - isclosed: false
```